# Webpack external module gives an error on optimization

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack

I'm new to Node and Angular but I have been tasked with updating an application using them.

When I run `ng build --configuration production --base-href` on the code I updated I get

```
Error: Optimization error [main.0a57bb482e1539bc.js]: Error: Transform failed with 1 error:
main.0a57bb482e1539bc.js:78551:5: error: Expected identifier but found "="
    at failureErrorWithLog (C:\Users\[redacted]\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1493:15)
    at C:\Users\[redacted]\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1282:29
    at C:\Users\[redacted]\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:629:9
    at handleIncomingPacket (C:\Users\[redacted]\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:726:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (C:\Users\[redacted]\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:596:7)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
```

If I run `ng build --configuration production --base-href --optimization false` it builds and I can see the line causing the error (main.0a57bb482e1539bc.js:78551) is:

```
// EXTERNAL MODULE: buffer/
var  = __webpack_require__(7555);
```

I can tell it's obviously syntactically incorrect.

`buffer` is being used as a dependency of `// CONCATENATED MODULE: ./node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/es/AuthenticationDetails.js`

However if I create a new app and use the code `import {AuthenticationDetails} from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";` in it I don't have this problem. What I see instead is this line:

```
/* harmony import */ var buffer__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! buffer */ 7555);
```

What I would like to know is what is causing my updated code to use `// EXTERNAL MODULE: buffer/` and how I can change it to not have the problem maybe by using `/* harmony import */`.

Angular CLI: 13.0.3
Node: 14.16.1

Comment: Have you checked the version between the two? I'm guessing it's a bug that was identified and fixed in the later version.

Comment: Same version of Angular CLI: 13.0.3 Node: 14.16.1 and amazon-cognito-identity-js.

Comment: Essentially I would never suggest this, but since it is an issue is in the node_modules file, go ahead and try deleting the node_modules and npm install from scratch (if you already haven't tried).

Comment: Tried that and deleted package-lock.json with it too.

Comment: More than likely the issue is that something in this application is modifying the [Webpack "externals"](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals) configuration resulting in broken output. It is a common workaround to make externals entries for Node.js modules [such as "buffer"](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html). Check your `angular.json` for mention of `buffer`, and for any Angular CLI plugin which allows custom webpack configuration.

Comment: I see a similar issue on github, maybe follow that?
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3973

Comment: @William Lahti unfortunately that didn't help.

Comment: @Dementic thanks for the link it helped me find a workaround.
I found a workaround by downgrading to "aws-sdk": "2.686.0", it uses a deprecated buffer version (4.9.1) but build without errors.
If I try to use "aws-sdk": "2.687.0" it uses a buffer version 4.9.2 but throws the error while building.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error after upgrading to angular 13, using cognito and aws-sdk,
What worked was removing both package-lock.json and node_modules and running "npm install" again.

Comment: this solved the issue, indeed .. thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Experienced the same build issue when upgrading from Angular 11 -> 12.

**Original version - Optimization error**

```
"amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^5.2.4",
```

**Downgraded version - No Optimization error**

```
"amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^3.3.3",
```

No degradation to the app found by reducing the version. "3.3.3" is the latest stable version of amazon-cognito-identity-js.